# How to open new terminal maximized without using 3rd party plugins?

Tags: gnome-terminal

Everytime I open a new terminal I want it to be maximized. I don't want to use a 3rd party plugin. How can I achieve this ? (initial terminal size in gnome-terminal doesn't work properly since it isn't really maximized)

Comment: You can achieve it easily.. See `man gnome-terminal` and you will have maximized option.. Then edit the..`.desktop` file and edit the `exec` command..

Comment: I am sure it is easy... could you also explain the steps since the manual doesn't explain much other than setting up a custom profile which I can also edit using the Edit->Preferences tab?

Comment: What's ur Ubuntu version? And Full screen or maximized??

Comment: 18 and you're right, I meant maximized :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open gnome-terminal
2. Make the window maximized
3. run `tput cols` note down the value
4. run `tput lines` note down the value
5. Create a new profile with any preferred name of your choice
6. Change the terminal size values under "Text" Tab.
7. Open the desktop file from `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop` Please note that this step 7 could be little tricky if you want to make the changes locally with out editing system files.
8. Edit the `Exec` line to match with the profile name
   for example: `Exec=gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=PRATAP`
9. Save the file and close.

Tested in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1204959/739431 read the comments in this post for clarity on point number 7 above..

Comment: Awesome ! Step 1-5 was already enough it seems !

Answer (score 0):

**Maximize when launched through Applications**

1. Copy the system desktop file `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop` to your local `.local/share/applications` folder.
2. Edit the `Exec=gnome-terminal` line to read

   Exec=gnome-terminal --maximize

This will maximize each new instance of the terminal when you launch it through the menu.

**Maximize when launched by keyboard shortcut**

When using a shortcut to launch the terminal ("Settings", "Keyboard shortcuts"), edit the command by adding the `--maximize` option.

*Notes*

1) If you want the change to affect all users, directly edit the global `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop` file as administrator.

2) Instead of `--maximize`, you can also use the option `--full-screen` to have an even more immersive terminal experience.